# Symfony firewall doesn't redirect me if i'm not login

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, firewall

Ok guys, it has been 10 hours that I search a solution for my problem. My firewall on Symfony 2.7 doesn't redirect me if i'm not logged in.

If I go on domain.com/admin/, the firewall should redirect me on /login, but not.

I use FOSUSerBundle.
I alway obtain this error message :

> You are not authenticated 401 Unauthorized - HttpException 1 linked
>   Exception: AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException »

Here is my code:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    admin:
        pattern: ^/
        context: site
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path: /admin/logout
        anonymous: false
```

My access control:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Here is the code in PhpStorm if you prefer :
    [image: Image1]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to set `anonymous` to `true` for admin firewall. And don't forget clear cache

Comment: I have already try this with no success :/ With anonymous to true, the error message is : "You do not have the necessary permissions - 403 Forbidden - AccessDeniedHttpException" (cache is cleared)

Comment: Could you try to set `pattern: ^/admin/` for admin firewall?

Comment: Ok wow finally I found the problem!! FOSRestBundle have a conflict with FOSUserBundle. If I disable RestBundle in config.yml, all works!! Thanks for your time Victor, I really apreciate!

Comment: @coolfarmer you should post your solution as answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem!! FOSRestBundle have a conflict with FOSUserBundle. If I disable RestBundle in config.yml, all works!!

So, I just move my API bundle in another symfony project.
One project for my API and one project for my site.